# How to change default port no of my .NET core 6 API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am trying to change default port from properties section of project but I am not able to see any options.

I am using visual studio 2022 with .NET core 6.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET Core API? Or some other kind?

Comment: Yes, It is .net core api

Comment: I recommend adding the `[asp.net-core]` tag then.

Comment: oops I missed it, thanks

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The port is defined in the endpoints and there are multiple ways to change them:

### For Development purposes

You can change in `launchSettings.json` file inside Properties folder:

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:22963",
      "sslPort": 44349
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "UrlTest": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7244;http://localhost:5053",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Server Endpoints

There is a file in root folder called `appsettings.json` with you can change the server related configuration, this is an example with Kestrel:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5400"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5401"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### From command line

You can run the application with the `--urls` parameter to specify the ports:

```
dotnet run --urls http://localhost:8076
```

### Environment Variable

You can set the `ASPNETCORE_URLS`.

### From source code

You can pass the Url to `Run` method:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run("http://localhost:6054");
```

Or the [UseUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.hostingabstractionswebhostbuilderextensions.useurls?view=aspnetcore-6.0) extension method:

there was a bug using this method but it seems solved now [#38185](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38185)

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://localhost:3045");
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

#### Source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0

A good documentation about the deploy:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: tried "Server Endpoints" method on Ubuntu with Apache and reverse proxy with no success but using "From source code" worked fine

Comment: lanuchSettings.json is broken in dotnet 6.0. See the answer here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69932090/dotnet-watch-ignores-portnumber-launchsettings-json-after-upgrade-to-net-6

Answer (score 8):

**Quick solution:**

In `Program.cs` :

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.Run();
}
else
{
    app.Run("http://127.0.0.1:8080");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set it from the launch profile setting

Click on the Dropdown on the run button.

[image]

Now click on debug properties.
By clicking on that launch profile window will open.

now you can change the port from the app URL from here.

[image]

Edit: Add on

You can also change it from the project profile as below.

[image]

Comment: OP might be using Visual Studio but a lot of developers use Rider or VS Code. A more generic answer would be more helpful.