# Add Listening Adrees to CoreWcf Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, corewcf

I want to change listening adress. I see the localhost5203 whenever I try to test on SoapUI.

How can I change it? I used to "web.config", "wcf.config", AddServiceEndpoint although I couldn do what I want.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mFKU.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change default port no of my .NET core 6 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70332897/how-to-change-default-port-no-of-my-net-core-6-api)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, click on `Debug` --> `{Project Name} Debug Properties`
Once the window opens, simply select the debug configuration that you're using, and scroll down to `App URL`
You can change your ports here.

In order to set your port for your Kubernetes deployment, which is a different question altogether, you need to follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/containerized-lifecycle/design-develop-containerized-apps/build-aspnet-core-applications-linux-containers-aks-kubernetes) to correctly setup the deployment.

Comment: This works on my local. However listening address doesnt change when the project works on Kubernetes

Comment: Added a link to documentation regarding port setup in Kubernetes